# Package 'emacs-25' is unavail

Tags: package-repositories

*I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 with Emacs 24.5*

If I run:

```
M-x package-refresh-contents [RET]
```

I get back the message:

```
Contacting host: melpa.org:443
```

If I try to install this package with:

```
M-x package-install [RET] indium [RET]
```

I get back:

```
Package 'emacs-25' is unavailable
```

Comment: What Emacs version are you using? (Is it less than 25?)

Comment: @npostavs using 24

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Evidentially the `indium` package has an explicit dependency on Emacs 25, and therefore you cannot install it on Emacs 24.

Comment: Actually, you should be able to install it if you run `(add-to-list 'package--builtin-versions '(emacs 25))` first. Whether it will work is a different question.

Comment: In general that sounds like a really bad idea :)