# Trying to install org-ref package, but getting error 'emacs-25.1' unavailable

Tags: package, org-ref, emacs24

I am trying to install `org-ref` package but getting error

```
package-compute-transaction: Package 'emacs-25.1' is unavailable.
```

I searched `Stack overflow`, `Stack Exchange Emacs`, and `github`.  I've found many solutions like [this](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/34296/package-emacs-25-is-unavail) but isn't working for me.

I am using `Emacs 25.1` in `Ubuntu 16.4`.

**Edit: I am using Emacs 24.5.1** version.

I was able to install `org-ref` earlier but need to reinstall as it got corrupted.

Comment: first of all try `M-x emacs-version` before installing it, you won't be the first nor the last who had several emacs versions installed in several paths and trying to install the wrong version.

Comment: I have only one emacs versions and it is 24.5.1

Answer (score 1):

You need to upgrade your emacs to at least Emacs 25.1.

I'm not sure if each Ubuntu LTS provides updated stable packages beyond the point they released the distro, `emacs26` now, but if not you can either compile it yourself or look for a suitable ppa as [Kevin Kelley's](https://launchpad.net/~kelleyk/+archive/ubuntu/emacs/+packages)

Comment: I managed to do it with my 24.1 version itself.  Thanks.